# Dojo dijit framework vs some CSS framework

Tags: css, dojo, css-frameworks

What do you think about Dojo dijit framework?
Is Dojo ditit better than some CSS framework?

I have had problems with dijits when I generated some dijits with layouts in my comet app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do. Most CSS frameworks don't come with a full widget library. They're usually more for setting consistent styles on text etc.

I'm not sure you can really compare the two

Comment: How dijits will be displayed on iPad or iPhone?

Comment: Most of them work OK, although not all. Better support is being added in trunk at the moment. Any you're trying to use? Have you seen dojox.mobile?

Comment: I'm going to try it. Looks very interesting. Thanks for replies.